# SBT run stopped working recently with nothing changed in Play services project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

You might think I ran into a XY-problem. I think that is not the case.

I am working on a project where

1. (PROD) I can run the Play Framework services using

   ```
   sbt dist
   ```

   And then running the executable script from `target/universal/*`.
2. (DEV) But not the development server using

   ```
   sbt run\ PORT_NUM
   ```

The second used to work a few days ago. Now (without any code change) I cannot run the DEV server anymore. It shows the following error if consume the API.

```
[error] java.io.IOException: Resource temporarily unavailable
[error]     at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:207)
[error]     at jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:245)
[error]     at jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:257)
[error]     at jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:194)
[error]     at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readCharacter(ConsoleReader.java:2151)
[error]     at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readCharacter(ConsoleReader.java:2141)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.waitEOF$1(PlayInteractionMode.scala:62)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.$anonfun$waitForKey$2(PlayInteractionMode.scala:73)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.$anonfun$doWithoutEcho$1(PlayInteractionMode.scala:80)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.$anonfun$doWithoutEcho$1$adapted(PlayInteractionMode.scala:77)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.withConsoleReader(PlayInteractionMode.scala:57)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.doWithoutEcho(PlayInteractionMode.scala:77)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.$anonfun$waitForKey$1(PlayInteractionMode.scala:73)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.$anonfun$waitForKey$1$adapted(PlayInteractionMode.scala:60)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.withConsoleReader(PlayInteractionMode.scala:57)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.waitForKey(PlayInteractionMode.scala:60)
[error]     at play.sbt.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.waitForCancel(PlayInteractionMode.scala:83)
[error]     at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.$anonfun$playRunTask$3(PlayRun.scala:125)
[error]     at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.$anonfun$playRunTask$3$adapted(PlayRun.scala:65)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
```

Seems a deadlock issue to me, how to proceed further and solve this?

Here is a list of things I tried:

1. Changing the version of installed system SBT
2. Changing the version of SBT in build.properties to latest (1.2.6)

> **Update 1**:
>   The whole system works on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. I am trying to figure out why it isn't working in 18.04 LTS.
>
> **Update 2a**:
>   On the machine where it works (it is running on a VM installed in Mac OS Mojave, and the OS is Ubuntu *server*),
>
> Java version (`$ java -version`) is
>
> ```
> openjdk version "1.8.0_191" 
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.16.04.1-b12) 
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
> ```
>
> Ubuntu version (`$ lsb_release -a`) is
>
> ```
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
> Release:    16.04
> Codename:   xenial
> ```
>
> **Update 2b**:
>   On the machine where it doesn't work (it is running on desktop system, and the OS is Ubuntu *desktop*),
>
> Java version (`$ java -version`) is
>
> ```
> openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.16.04.1-b12)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
> ```
>
> Ubuntu version (`$ lsb_release -a`) is
>
> ```
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
> Release:    16.04
> Codename:   xenial
> ```
>
> **Update 3**:
>   Created an issue on `sbt`'s [GitHub](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4547)

Comment: Myself and my colleague are also facing this same problem on Ubuntu 16.04.5 64bit and Ubuntu 18.04 64bit. We both use SBT version 0.13.16 and Oracle JDK 1.8.0_202. @Fahad were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Also we use Play framework version 2.4

Comment: Updated the description of question with two new updates. @lkt

Comment: Also put an issue to `sbt`'s GitHub https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4547

Comment: May be related with a broken kernel patch that got released recently. See https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/ubuntu-18-04-bad-kernel-update.357871/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new kernel version as the other answers suggested, is having issues. 
So far no fix is being distributed in new updates. You can downgrade back to previous working kernel version which is `4.15.0-43`. 
Follow this [link](http://karlcode.owtelse.com/blog/2017/03/13/reverting-to-a-previous-kernel/) for details on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The newest kernel version 4.15.0-45 was the cause of the problem. I rebooted to 4.15.0-43 and it works fine now. Thanks @Renato

Answer (score 0):

Some notes for those broken on Ubuntu 16.04.
Kernel 4.4.0-142 is broken (and seems the latest), and booting into 4.4.0-141 fixes it.